# react scripts start - hot reload are too slow?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using **create-react-app** to create my react projects boilerplates but recently launching my projects with `npm start` is too slow and most recently hot reloading is slow take from 5 - 15 secs to rebuild the page after any change especially when rebuilding after an error.

I really don't know much about **webpack**, after some search i found that problem can be from **webpack** or **webpack-dev-server** but i don't know much about them
so i don't know from where should i move to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide any link, or list of commands you've used to create your `create-react-app` instance? I would say that this is connected to overall performance of your computer, since my CRA hot reload works normally. It could also be due to a large project.

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac my project is not too large, i have disabled firewall, but nothing changed, my computer is not so bad since projects used to work well previously, but later this changed

Comment: **off-topic**: my desktop never hot reloads, it is just stuck there lol. I have found out that repl.it's react reload times are pretty good, so I'm going to be using repl.it

Answer (score 1):

If you're developing a React project in a Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) environment, it's especially important that you work within the WSL2 directory structure for optimal I/O. For example, you'll want to put the project in "~/repos/my-project", not "/mnt/c/Users/my-username/repos/my-project". They aren't the same location. You can confirm this by running "explorer.exe ." from the terminal.